# Why Hibernate ignore ON DELETE NO ACTION?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My app uses Hibernate, Spring Data JPA and Spring MVC. Database is HSQLDB.

There are two entities, Student and Course. Their relationship is ManyToMany.

#### Student

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
    List<Course> courses;
    // other fields
}
```

#### Course

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "students_courses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
    List<Student> students;
    // other fields
}
```

#### Tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE students
(
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE global_seq PRIMARY KEY
    /* other fields */
);

CREATE TABLE courses
(
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE global_seq PRIMARY KEY
    /* other fields */
);

CREATE TABLE students_courses
(
    student_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    course_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student_course_idx UNIQUE (student_id, course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This controller I use for student:

```java
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM Student s WHERE s.id=:id")
    int delete(@Param("id") int id);

    // Other methods
```

By assignment, student removal is not possible if the student is associated with one or more courses. So I fixed the student_courses table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE students_courses
(
    student_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    course_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student_course_idx UNIQUE (student_id, course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id) /* removed delete cascading */,
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Okay, the change is here: `FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id)`, I removed `ON DELETE CASCADE`, that student removal will not possible if the student is associated with one or more courses. But Hibernate ignores it, and removes students easily even if they are associated with courses.

I tried to use `ON DELETE NO ACTION`, but it wasn't effective.

I wonder why Hibernate does not ignore `ON DELETE SET NULL` and throws error. But why does Hibernate ignore `ON DELETE NO ACTION`? How can I fix it?

Comment: Hibernate doesn't read the database schema, so it doesn't know that you changed the foreign key's `ON DELETE` option. To tell Hibernate, specify the `cascade` attribute on the `@ManyToMany` annotation.

Comment: @Andreas how i can use cascade? I think cascade in `@ManyToMany` and cascade in database have various function

Comment: @Andreas i want that student removal is not possible if the student is associated with one or more courses. How i can do it?

Comment: @Zhenyria `i want that student removal is not possible` - You want to have JDBC level exception for this operation?

Comment: @SternK I want to get exception when I try to delete a student associated with one or more courses. For example, I get an exception when I save an entity that already exists

Answer (score -1):

StudentRepository has Transactional(readOnly = true) annotation and you have delete method into it.

Comment: and? delete() marked with @Transactional without readOnly.

Comment: I mean issue could be the readOnly = true,and delete() inside the repository

Comment: so isn't `@Transactional (readOnly = true)` replaced by `@Transactional`?